# Laravel Query Builder with sum

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, sum

below is the query , and i am having this error

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax

```
        $games = DB::table('games')
        ->select('start','dayofweek','name','ins_id','location_id',
            DB::raw('SUM(reservations) as reservations'),
            DB::raw('SUM(reservationsmax) as reservationsmax'),
            DB::raw('SUM(entries) as entries'),
            DB::raw('SUM(entriesmax) as entriesmax'),
            DB::raw('(SUM(entries) / SUM(reservationsmax) * 100 as percentage'))
        ->where('club_id', $club_id)
        ->whereBetween('start', [$from, $to])
        ->where('hide_from_customers', 0)
        ->where('external_id', 0)
        ->orderBy('name')
        ->groupBy('start')
        ->groupBy('dayofweek')
        ->groupBy('name')
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

i have found the answer, i thought it will would help some one else as well.

```
$games = \App\Models\Games::select(DB::raw('start,dayofweek,name,instructor_id,location_id,SUM(reservations) as reservations,SUM(reservationsmax) as reservationsmax,SUM(entries) as entries,SUM(entriesmax) as entriesmax,(SUM(entries) / SUM(reservationsmax)) * 100 as percentage'))
            ->where('club_id', $club_id)
            ->whereBetween('start', [$from, $to])
            ->where('hide_from_customers', 0)
            ->where('external_id', 0)
            ->orderBy('name')
            ->groupBy('start')
            ->groupBy('dayofweek')
            ->groupBy('name')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Something like this ....  

$games = DB::table('games')
    ->select(DB::raw('
        SUM(reservations) as reservations, 
        SUM(reservationsmax) as reservationsmax,
        SUM(reservationsmax) as reservationsmax,
        SUM(entries) as entries,
        SUM(entriesmax) as entriesmax,
        SUM(entries) / SUM(reservationsmax) * 100 as percentage'))
            ->where('club_id', $club_id)
                    ->whereBetween('start', [$from, $to])
                    ->where('hide_from_customers', 0)
                    ->where('external_id', 0)
                    ->orderBy('name')
                    ->groupBy('start')
                    ->groupBy('dayofweek')
                    ->groupBy('name')
                    ->get();
```

Comment: Ii have tried with single group by ->groupBy('start','dayofweek','name'), still hacing same error

Comment: try running the query without any of the where,orderBy and groupBy clauses. Then add each one in one at a time.As its hard to find the issue when i dont have the vairable values for $from, $to etc ....

Comment: club_id = '25', hide_from_customers = 0, to = '2017-05-11', from = '2017-05-01'

Comment: Thanks for your help, i have fixed the query builder syntax.

Comment: No Problem mate !